# pl/sql-create trigger on a table -whenever a new record is inserted in the same table another column of the table should be updated

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsql-psp

```
create trigger calculation after insert on employee 
for each row
begin
if :new.updated_sal is null
then
update employee set updated_sal= (10/100)* salary
where id=:new.id;
end if;
end;
```

I would like to create a trigger on the employee table, whenever a new record is inserted in the same table, a 10% of salary in the salary column should be calculated and put into another column updated_sal.
If I try to insert a new record, it is showing that the table is mutated, etc

Answer (score 0):

It's just the `:new` pseudorecord you need:

```
create trigger calculation 
  after insert on employee 
  for each row
begin
  if :new.updated_sal is null then
     :new.updated_sal := (10/100) * :new.salary; 
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: But it must be a *before* trigger. An *after* trigger cannot change a column value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use before insert trigger,
And use :New.updated_sal:= :new.salary * somevalue
To assign salary.